# How to set To emailaddress fo ForwardTicket

Tags: perl, otrs

I'm using OTRS 3.2 and I want to automatically set the `To` email address to a value based on one of the dynamicfields. This worked fine in 3.1 with the code below in AgentTicketForward

```
if ($Data{DynamicField_Test} eq 'ABC') {
        $Data{To}="abc\@example.com";
} elsif ($Data{DynamicField_Test} eq 'XYZ') {
      $Data{To}="xyz\@example.com";
}
```

After upgrading to OTRS 3.2 it stopped working. Not only doesn't it fill in the email address but it also won't send any emails if the To field is filled manually.

Does anyone know what was changed in 3.2 so it stops working?

Answer (score 1):

@ is sigil which represents perl arrays and double quotes interpolate arrays to string.

You'll need to backslash it inside double quotes (\@) or use single quotes to avoid interpolation.

```
if ($Data{DynamicField_Test} eq 'ABC') {
        $Data{To} = 'abc@example.com';
}
elsif ($Data{DynamicField_Test} eq 'XYZ') {
      $Data{To} = 'xyz@example.com';
}
# default for $Data{To}
else { 
      $Data{To} = '...' 
}
```

Comment: You're right that my original code wouldn't work. I have added an escape (\) for the @ in the email address, just like the real code is. The code works (it doesn't throw errors) but just doesn't fill the To field in the form.

Comment: I would add else {} block in case when $Data{DynamicField_Test} doesn't satisfy previous conditions.

Comment: If it doens't satisfy, it can be blank so it's ok. The real problem is that the form doesn't get filled in 3.2 but it did in 3.1 with the same code.

Comment: You'll need to debug using Dumper or similar at critical point to inspect variables (if you know what they should contain); ie. use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%Data;